# Can this be considered Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: java, treeview, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently using `Java` to code a program that can have conversations and solve problems.

So far, the program can only have conversations. The solving problems is still in process.
The program is capable of learning, however, it's how I made that happen that gives me doubts.

The way my program learns new words is it stores them in a `TreeView` menu as branches.
Each `branch` (word) has sub-branches that give the word meaning.
Each sub-branch has sort of like different tags to differentiate the relation to the main branch.

For example, if I teach it the word `Hello` and type `Hello>>Hi`, it then saves `Hi` as a sub-branch in the main branch `Hello`, but in the form of `=s=Hi=s=` to tell the program it's a synonym of `Hello`, so it can use `Hi` instead of `Hello`. More synonyms can be added.

Though if you type, for example, `Hello<>Greeting`, it stores the branch `Greeting` in `Hello` in the form of `=m=Greeting=m=`. To show that `Hello` is a type if greeting.
There is more, but too much to explain.

Just my cheap attempt on A.I.

Can this class as a program learning? Or have I got a long way to go?

Comment: I don't know if it's AI or not, but you seem to be doing exciting stuff... All the very best...:)

Comment: @Codebender Thank you :)

Comment: AI is pretty broadly defined, so whether your program crosses the line between "clever state machine" and AI is basically a judgement call. This is probably off topic for SO, as it's not really a programming question (or to put it a bit differently, any answer would not have an actionable effect on your code). Neat program, though!

Comment: @yshavit Yeah I had a feeling it would be off topic. It's just that I asked this on Yahoo Answers and no one answered. And thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have actually started to learn AI. And this what you do is called giving `ground terms` manually for the machine. But  AI is something that the system learns by itself. For example, now you have taught that `hi` is a way of greeting, if some other user greets it, it must greet him too. And yes you will be writing logic for that too. You cannot fully achieve AI such that the computer learns itself without writing any logic for it (only fictional characters like `Jarvis` can do so).

To be frank I am not deep into `machine learning` and AI. But to my perception, I think some sort of implementation which involves human like thinking would be better. For example, try to implement a `chess` game. In that you have `back tracking`. You can get a better understanding. Properties of each coin and their power is what you give as `ground terms`(base knowledge). And based on the moves of User, system must analyze future moves and predict user's view and `backtrack` to make its move.

Not sure whether I answered your question, but you seem to be doing cool stuff, thumbs up for you, move on and develop cool and small scale AI systems first which involves lot of `computation` and `Algorithm` stuffs.

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question. I'm trying to study the AI in `chess` and it seems like really cool and complicated stuff. But I'll stick at it :).

Answer (score 2):

As per definition of AI:- It's the capacity to perform operations analogous to learning and decision making in humans.

Your program do seems to learn the new words and make decision on what type of word it is i.e. Hello, Hi -->Greeting

But more than learning, how you control its learning will be AI. For example if I use a bad word for greeting, it should not learn it.   Controlled learning and decision-making do make your program a true AI program.